# No table numbering with pander in bookdown:html_document2

Tags: knitr, bookdown, pander

pander does not include table numbering when used with bookdown::html_document2. Did I miss some option?

````
---
title: "Pander Table Numbering"
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

# Chapter 1

```{r}
library(knitr)
library(pander)
# Table 1.1
kable(head(iris), caption = "Iris with kable")
# Another Table 1.1 (ok, same chunk = same table)
kable(head(mtcars), caption = "Mtcars kable")
```

```{r}
# No table number
pander(head(iris), caption = "Iris with pander")
```

```{r}
# Table 1.2
kable(head(mtcars), caption = "Mtcars kable")
```
````

Comment: @daroczig Too bad I somehow missed you at user2017

Comment: Hope to see you next time :) Regarding this problem, I've opened a [GH ticket](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/307) and hope to resolve that with some help. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with the `bookdown` internals, but maybe adding a new param to `pander` might solve this pretty easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I am an extremely grateful user of `bookdown`!

I have tried to achieve the same thing using `pander` instead of `kable`. The reason for this is that `kable` or `kableExtra` do not render markup text in tables of pdf output, which is a huge current drawback... So for pdf output, `kable` will not render things like literature references such as `@smith2018-so` or `*italic*` and so on... which is a pain. Hopefully, a patch will be provided soon. To take the same code above, I was able to have the referencing work with `pander` provided several changes in the code above. Another thing about `kable`, one must add `longtable=T` otherwise the table floats down to the bottom of a page in pdf output.

First I added `documentclass: article` in the YAML, and then I named the the code chunks. But the thing that really make it work in pander is by changing the caption to `caption = '(\\#tab:chunkname) Iris with pander')`. The trick was to add the double `\\` which I could not find in the `bookdown` reference. So in the end, a code that worked for both html and pdf outputs is :

````
---
title: "Pander Table Numbering"
documentclass: article
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2: default
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
---

# Chapter 1

Table \@ref(tab:TabKable1)

```{r "TabKable1", results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(pander)
# Table 1.1
knitr::kable(head(iris), caption = 'Iris with kable', longtable =T)
# Another Table 1.1 (ok, same chunk = same table)
#kable(head(mtcars), caption = "Mtcars kable")
```

Table \@ref(tab:TabPander1)

```{r "TabPander1"}
# No table number
pander(head(iris), caption = 'Iris with pander')
```

Table \@ref(tab:TabPander2)

```{r "TabPander2"}
# table number this time!!
pander(head(iris), caption = '(\\#tab:TabPander2) Iris with pander')
```


Table \@ref(tab:TabKable2)

```{r "TabKable2"}
# Table 1.2
kable(head(mtcars), caption = "Mtcars kable", longtable=T)
````

Comment: I have accepted the workaround as the current answer now.

Comment: The workaround produces correct output only in html. Verbatim output in Word, no output at all in pdf

Answer (score 4):

From https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html

> If you decide to use other R packages to generate tables, you have to make sure the label for the table environment appears in the beginning of the table caption in the form `(\#label)` (again, `label` must have the prefix `tab:`).

The reason here is that `pander::pander()` doesn't produce proper `(\#tab:***)`. You can report the bug to the author of **pander**.

## `kable(head(iris), caption = "Iris with kable")`

```
Table: (\#tab:unnamed-chunk-1)Iris with kable

Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length   Petal.Width  Species 
-------------  ------------  -------------  ------------  --------
        5.1           3.5            1.4           0.2  setosa  
        4.9           3.0            1.4           0.2  setosa  
        4.7           3.2            1.3           0.2  setosa  
        4.6           3.1            1.5           0.2  setosa  
        5.0           3.6            1.4           0.2  setosa  
        5.4           3.9            1.7           0.4  setosa
```

## `pander(head(iris), caption = "Iris with pander")`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length   Petal.Width   Species 
-------------- ------------- -------------- ------------- ---------
    5.1            3.5           1.4            0.2       setosa  

    4.9             3            1.4            0.2       setosa  

    4.7            3.2           1.3            0.2       setosa  

    4.6            3.1           1.5            0.2       setosa  

    5             3.6           1.4            0.2       setosa  

    5.4            3.9           1.7            0.4       setosa  
-------------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Iris with pander
```

Comment: Thanks for finding the right spot in the docs. Since the package author @daroczig is one of the fastest SO responders and sometimes corrects these bugs within hours, he probably is on vacation.

Comment: @daroczig: Any progress on https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/307. I still cannot use pander when tables must be numbered

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example above, I created a function that creates the appropriate label for html and latex, using the `bookdown` cross-ref formating

````
---
title: "Pander Table Numbering"
documentclass: article
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2: default
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
---
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
addLabel <- function(caption = "", tag = "tab") {
  chunkLabel <- knitr::opts_current$get("label")
  pretag <- if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
    paste0("\\label{", tag, ":",chunkLabel , "}")
  } else {
      paste0("(\\#", tag, ":", chunkLabel, ")"))
    }
  paste0(pretag, caption)
}
```

# Chapter 1

Table \@ref(tab:TabPander1)

```{r "TabPander1"}
pander(head(iris), caption = addLabel('Iris with pander'))
```

Table \@ref(tab:TabPander2)

```{r "TabPander2"}
pander(head(iris), caption = 'addLabel('Iris with pander'))
```
````

Answer (score 1):

The magic seems to be the `:`  prefix, i.e.
`pander(caption = ': (\\#tab:your-label) Your caption')` allows you to refer to the table along the lines of `Table \@ref(tab:your-label) ...`.