# How to disable automatic table number for bookdown::html_document2?

Tags: r, r-markdown

For `html_document` or `pdf_document`, there have been solutions to suppress automatic table name and number, [for example,] ([How to suppress automatic table name and number in an .Rmd file using xtable or knitr::kable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182147/how-to-suppress-automatic-table-name-and-number-in-an-rmd-file-using-xtable-or)).
However, adding the following in the YAML section

```
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{caption}
```

and the following before the code chunk

```
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}
```

does not work for `html_document2`.
Knitted from the following .rmd file, the automatic table name and number "Table 1.1: " cannot be disabled in the output html file. Thanks in advance for help!

````
---
title: "Suppress automatic table name and number"
author: Generated by bookdown
output:
  bookdown::html_document2: default
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{caption}
---
# https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cross-ref.html

\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}

```{r myirischunk, results = 'asis', tab.cap = NULL, echo = TRUE}
print(knitr::kable(head(iris), caption = "Table 1.a - First own table name"))

print(knitr::kable(tail(iris), caption = "Table 1.b - Last own table name"))
````

Comment: If the toolchain is to go Rmd -> LaTeX -> HTML, then it would be surprising that this doesn't work. Unfortunately I'm not intimately familiar how the toolchain for making HTML goes, but if it's not using LaTeX, I doubt importing a LaTeX package would work.

Comment: Thanks! I tried [pander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651426/no-table-numbering-with-pander-in-bookdownhtml-document2). It seems to work.